# Imported Variable not translated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm starting to work with react and I'm little bit confused about importing images.

This is my code and it should render logo:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Data} from '../Data';
import logo from '../../images/logo.jpg';

export default() => {
    return (
        <nav className="navbar navbar-default">

            <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="navbar-header">
                    <Link to="/" className="navbar-brand"><img src="{logo}" alt="logo" /></Link>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" className="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        Toggle
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    );
}
```

But my logo isn't rendered.

1. I tried to `console.log(logo)` and it's outputing `client/images/logo.jpg`
2. Tried to replace `{logo}` with actual string "`client/images/logo.jpg`" and this way logo is rendered correctly

So my question is, variable `logo` isn't for some reason translating to string, why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<img src={logo} ... />
```

When you're doing that your way, you just pass string `"{logo}"` as prop

Comment: oh my god. That's it :D I'll accept your answer in 12 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is, variable logo isn't for some reason translating to string, why is that?

Because you are using the wrong syntax. When you use a string literal as prop value (i.e. `prop="value"`) then the value of the string is used without any interpolation. So the component is literally passed `{logo}` as source.

To pass the value of a variable (or any expression really), you have to use the form `prop={...}` (where `...` is your expression). I.e. in your example: `src={logo}`.